# how to combine 2 querys in the same vector (json_encode and php)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I believe it's a simple question
I want to run both queries but I don't know how

hello people, I believe this is a simple matter
I want execute the two queries

`SELECT * FROM diligencias WHERE idprocesso = '$process_id'` and
`SELECT * FROM processos WHERE id = '$process_id'`

code working only with one query:

```
<?php
include("../../includes/conectar.php");

if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['id']) != "")
{
    $process_id = $_POST['id'];
    $qryLista = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM processos WHERE id = '$process_id'");

    while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryLista)){
        $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado); 
    }    

    echo json_encode($vetor);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do the tables have the same column names?

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). `SELECT * FROM diligencias d JOIN processos p ON d.idprocessor = p.id WHERE p.id = :process_id` and see what comes out.

Comment: Thanks @danblack , i will read articles from sql injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tables don't have the same column names, you can simply `JOIN` them using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM processos p
JOIN diligencias d ON d.idprocesso = p.id
WHERE p.d = '$process_id'
```

If the tables do have similar column names, you will need to provide [column aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) for the overlapping names e.g.

```
SELECT p.*, d.id AS diligencias_id, d.xxx AS diligencias_xxx
FROM processos p
JOIN diligencias d ON d.idprocesso = p.id
WHERE p.d = '$process_id'
```

Note that in your existing code

```
isset($_POST['id']) != ""
```

should be

```
$_POST['id'] != ""
```

Also you are vulnerable to SQL injection, and should use a prepared query. For example:

```
$process_id = $_POST['id'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT *
    FROM processos p
    JOIN diligencias d ON d.idprocesso = p.id
    WHERE p.d = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $process_id);
$qryLista = $stmt->get_result();
while($resultado = $qryLista->fetch_assoc()){
    $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado); 
}
echo json_encode($vetor);
```